# Good use of certificates to sign a PDF

Tags: pdf, openssl, certificate, sign

I'm trying to sign a PDF in a PHP script with a certificate. Until now, I executed my test with a self-signed .crt file, generated with the command line :

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:1024 \
            -keyout tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.crt
```

(yes, i'm using tcpdf). It works fine.

But know, my company gave me real certificates (from tbs-certificats), and I'm a bit disappointed: I've a .cer, a .pem and a .p7b file...

I tried to use each of them in my script, but I've the error

```
Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign(): error getting private key
```

The code I use with a self-signed certificate :

```
// set certificate file
$certificate = 'file://data/cert/tcpdf.crt';

// set document signature
$pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate);
```

May I change something ? I'm not very familiar with the crypto world...

Answer (score 0):

We'll, first things first, you have to point your script to an existing file. In this case, the .cer file would contain the certificate, so try that instead of "/path/file.CRT".

---

Now the file extension vs. how the certificate is encoded is kinda unrelated I'm afraid, even if the names are inducing some confusion, see [this reference](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them).

I have no idea whether tcpdf supports both pem and der encoded files, because of the lack of documentation. They probably do, but just in case, here's how to work around it. Test commands will give you an "unable to load certificate" error if you assume the wrong encoding.

- testing for pem encoded files : `openssl x509 -in cert.cer -text -noout`
- testing for der encoded files : `openssl x509 -in certificate.der -inform der -text -noout`
- conversion from PEM to DER `openssl x509 -in cert.cer -outform der -out cert.der`
- conversion from DER to PEM `openssl x509 -in cert.cer -inform der -outform pem -out cert.pem`

Comment: Thanks for the link, very helpfull. However, i've the same issue. With the test commands i've found that my .cer and .pem files are both pem encoded. Same thing for my .crt self-signed.
So, I've try using the .cer instead of the .crt but i've the same issue...